# Get the latest message in a conversation between two users in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I'm writing a messaging system and I'm trying to find the latest messages in each conversation for a given user (id = 46). Here's what I currently have:

```
SELECT sender, receiver, MAX(created_at) maxDate 
FROM message 
WHERE sender = 46 OR receiver = 46 
GROUP BY sender, receiver;
```

Which outputs:

```
45  46  2018-09-24 21:14:47
46  45  2018-09-24 21:10:32
46  1   2018-09-24 21:08:47
46  25  2018-09-23 22:25:09
```

The problem with this is that the conversation between 45 and 46 is one conversation, but it's giving two rows in the result, because each person sent messages to each other.

I'd like to instead only get the latest message from the entire conversation, so I would somehow modify the SQL to instead get the following:

```
45  46  2018-09-24 21:14:47
46  1   2018-09-24 21:08:47
46  25  2018-09-23 22:25:09
```

The other row was dropped because in their conversation 45 sent the most recent message.

I've been banging my head against this for a while and can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the fastest way to do this would

```
SELECT GREATEST(sender, receiver), LEAST(sender, receiver), MAX(created_at) AS maxdate
FROM t
WHERE sender = 46
  OR receiver = 46 
GROUP BY GREATEST(sender, receiver), LEAST(sender, receiver);
```

Or you could try with `DISTINCT ON`

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(GREATEST(sender, receiver), LEAST(sender, receiver)) GREATEST(sender, receiver), LEAST(sender, receiver),  created_at AS maxdate
FROM t
WHERE sender = 46
  OR receiver = 46 
ORDER BY GREATEST(sender, receiver), LEAST(sender, receiver), created_at DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The second query didn't work for me `ERROR: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions` but that's fine because it looks like the first query works and is shorter! Gonna read this over to digest it.

Comment: @ChronBag fixed

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM message m 
WHERE 46 IN (m.sender, m.receiver) AND
      (LEAST(m.sender, m.receiver), GREATEST(m.sender, m.receiver), created_at) IN 
       (SELECT LEAST(m2.sender, m2.receiver), GREATEST(m2.sender, m2.receiver), MAX(m2.created_at)
        FROM message m2
        GROUP BY LEAST(m2.sender, m2.receiver), GREATEST(m2.sender, m2.receiver)
       );
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/XJDD19108) is a rextester illustrating the logic.

Comment: That's quite the query! I tried running it on my data but it only outputs one row though (instead of 3 like it should)

Comment: @ChronBag . . . Typos on the aliases.

Comment: Oh neat that works. I'm amazed how quickly you came up with such a complex query. Been trying to figure this out for an hour or two. I wonder if there is a way to simplify it though.